# How to get the failures count after Spring Batch Job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'd like to specific a skip policy on spring batch jobs. So that the job is not terminated on just a few failures. Anyhow, when the job finished, I'd like to get the count how many failures actually occurred.

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("step")....skipLimit(10).skip(CustomException.class);
JobExecution result = jobLauncher.run(job, params);
result.getAllFailureExceptions().size(); //always = 0
```

Problem: the failure size is always `= 0` as when errors are supposed to be skipped they are not counted. But if I remove the `skipLimit`, then the job will terminate immediately.

So how can I get the error count after job was run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
int failures = 0;
Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions = result.getStepExecutions();
for(StepExecution se : stepExecutions)
failures += se.getSkipCount();
```

In result you should have the number of failures